How to solve "action.setParams is not a function" error for an Aura component?
This is the component callAccountSpecificMethod that I want to use in another component:
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
    <aura:attribute name="method" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="accountId" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <lightning:spinner variant="brand" aura:id="spinner" class="slds-show backgroundSpinner"></lightning:spinner>
</aura:component>

The beginning of its JS controller looks like this:
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        let action = component.get('v.method');
        action.setParams({ accountId : component.get('v.accountId') });

And the using component looks like this:
<aura:component controller="AccountController" implements="force:hasRecordId">
    <c:callAccountSpecificMethod method="c.getHistoricOrdersFromERP" accountId="{!v.recordId}"/>
</aura:component>

This gives the runtime error

Error while creating component for lightning component quick action
[Action failed: c:callAccountSpecificMethod$controller$doInit
[action.setParams is not a function]]

I have been playing around with #, !, { and }, with or without quotes, but all it gets me is the above error.
Where should I put what symbols to get this running?

Do you have checked this? - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4MQ1SAN

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation


@TusharJadav No, and it solved my problem. Thanks very much, I will post an answer. Somehow Google didn't show me that page.

The solution was indeed just a few crucial characters.
I changed:
<c:callAccountSpecificMethod method="c.getHistoricOrdersFromERP" accountId="{!v.recordId}"/>

into:
<c:callAccountSpecificMethod method="{!c.getHistoricOrdersFromERP}" accountId="{!v.recordId}"/>

And then it worked. So the problem was not the accountId parameter (as I first thought), but the method one. The error action.setParams is not a function is not very helpful.
